# Use the value from 'Input' as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an input box on my HTML page

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name" placeholder="12345">
```

Say a user enters '000123' and then clicks the 'Call button'

```
<button name="Call" type="submit" id="Call-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Call</button>
```

I want to be able to use the Value (000123) in a later script

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: $( "txt_name" ).val()})
```

My page is very simple,

```
1) User opens
2) Enters a number
3) Click button (Value Captured)
4) Click another button (Send Value)
```

Comment: All of this looks okay, except you didn't include the `#` symbol in your jQuery selector to specify that you're looking for the ID of an element. Should be: `$('#txt_name')`

Comment: Great, Silly mistake, tanks for spotting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var data;
   $('#Call-submit').on('click',function(){
     data = $( "#txt_name" ).val();
   })
```